# Definition of accumulation point of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definition

I have the following definition of an accumulation point of a sequence:

$P$ is an accumulation point of the sequence $(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ if: $$\forall \epsilon>0, \ \  \forall N\in\mathbb{N}, \ \exists n\in\mathbb{N} \ \ with \ \ n>N \\  s.t \ \ |x_n-P|<\epsilon$$

I am not sure if this definition is fine. I know the existance of other definitions such as the one given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point and the definition given in Terance Tao analysis book (image below). But I would want to know if someone has encounter something like this before.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is not in $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$
this definition is equivalent to the one you provided in Wikipedia (I can not see the one in your image) in $\mathbb{R}$.

Assume that $P$ is an acumulation point acording to your definition, then for any neighbourhood $Q$ of $P$ you can define a ball of center $P$ and radius $\epsilon$ small enough such that the ball is inside $Q$.  Then by taking $N$ such that $\vert x_n - P \vert$ for all $n \geq N$ you get a point inside $Q$ (for example $X_{N+1}$).

On the other hand if $P$ is an acumulation point acording to the definition in your link then you can construct a sequence $ \lbrace x_n \rbrace$ as the definition that you proposed.

Observe that you did not need to be in $\mathbb{R}$ only to be in a space where the distances are defined.

However if $P$ is in the sequence the definitions are not equivalent, for example look at the case $x_n=P \ \forall \ n$.  Then according to your definition $P$ is an accumulation point but it is not for the one you provided in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you. And I am adding the image since i forgot

Comment: The definition of your image is equivalent to the one that you proposed.                          To understand why they are different, the one that you provide is only for sequences, the one in Wikipedia is for any kind of sets. However as I said the one in Wikipedia is not a generalization.

Comment: When you say Q, what do you mean by it?

Comment: Oh, it is the name of the arbitrary neighbourhood . The definition of Wikipedia is harder to understand, to get an idea, draw a cross representing the point $P$. Then two rectangles around $P$ (one strictly smaller than the other),put $x_1$ inside the bigger rectangle but outside the smaller one and  $x_2$ inside the smaller one.   According to your definition $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be equal to $P$, according to the definition of Wikipedia they can not.